# MSDTC getting invoked. But why?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, async-await, msdtc

For my data access I use TransactionScopes at the API level to wrap entire operations in a single transaction so that my SQL operations can be somewhat composable.  I have a web project that hosts an API and a separate service library that is the implementation and calls to SQL.  At the beginning of an Operation (an API entry-point) I open the TransactionScope.  Whenever a SqlConnection is needed within the processing of the Operation, ask for the AmbientConnection instead of directly making a new connection.  AmbientConnection finds or creates a new SqlConnection for the current transation.  Doing this is supposed to allow for good composibility but also avoid the invocation of the MSDTC because it should keep using the same connection for the each suboperation within the transaction.  When the transaction is completed (with `scope.complete()`), the connection is automatically closed.

The problem is that every once in a while the MSDTC is still getting invoked and I cannot figure out why.  I've used this before sucessfully and I believe I never got an MSDTC invoked.  Two things seem different to me this time though: 1) I'm using SQL Server 2008 R1 (10.50.4000) - not my choice - and I'm aware that the MSDTC behavior changed beginning with this version and perhaps not all the kinks were worked out until later versions.  2) The use of async-await is new and I believe I'm having to use `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` to accommodate this new feature in case some part of the implementation is async.  Perhaps more measures are necessary.

I tried `Pooling=false` in the connection string in case it was MSDTC getting invoked because of two independent logical connections handled errantly under a single pooled connection.  But that didn't work.

#### API Operation

```
// Exposed API composing multiple low-level operations within a single TransactionScope
// independent of any database platform specifics.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMeTheTwoThings()
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        var result = new TwoThings(
            await serviceLayer.GetThingOne(),
            await serviceLayer.GetThingTwo());

        scope.Complete();

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

#### Service layer implementation

```
public async Task<ThingOne> GetThingOne()
{
    using (var cmd = connManagement.AmbientConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetThingOne";

        return (ThingOne)(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());
    }
}

public async Task<ThingTwo> GetThingTwo()
{
    using (var cmd = connManagement.AmbientConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetThingTwo";

        return (ThingTwo)(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());
    }
}
```

#### AmbientConnection implementation

```
internal class SQLConnManagement
{
    readonly string connStr;
    readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Transaction, SqlConnection> txConnections = new ConcurrentDictionary<Transaction, SqlConnection>();

    private SqlConnection CreateConnection(Transaction tx)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(this.connStr);

        // When the transaction completes, close the connection as well
        tx.TransactionCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            SqlConnection closing_conn;
            if (txConnections.TryRemove(e.Transaction, out closing_conn))
            {
                closing_conn.Dispose(); // closing_conn == conn
            }
        };

        conn.Open();

        return conn;
    }

    internal SqlConnection AmbientConnection
    {
        get
        {
            var txCurrent = Transaction.Current;

            if (txCurrent == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("An ambient transaction is required.");

            return txConnections.GetOrAdd(txCurrent, CreateConnection);
        }
    }

    public SQLConnManagement(string connStr)
    {
        this.connStr = connStr;
    }
}
```

Not to overcomplicate the post, but this might be relevant because it seems to me that every time MSDTC has been invoked the logged stack trace shows that this next mechanism has been involved.  Certain data I cache with the built in ObjetCache because it doesn't change often and so I just get it at most once per minute or whatever.  This is a little fancy, but I don't see why the Lazy generator would be treated any differently from a more typical call and why this specifically would cause the MSSDTC to sometimes be invoked.  I've tried `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication` too just in case but that doesn't help anyway (and then the exception just keeps getting delivered as the cached result for subsequent requests before the expiration, of course, and that's not desirable).

```
/// <summary>
/// Cache element that gets the item by key, or if it is missing, creates, caches, and returns the item
/// </summary>
static T CacheGetWithGenerate<T>(ObjectCache cache, string key, Func<T> generator, DateTimeOffset offset) where T : class
{
    var generatorWrapped = new Lazy<T>(generator, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);

    return ((Lazy<T>)cache.AddOrGetExisting(
        key,
        generatorWrapped,
        offset))?.Value ?? generatorWrapped.Value;
}

public ThingTwo CachedThingTwo
{
    get
    {
        return CacheGetWithGenerate(
            MemoryCache.Default,
            "Services.ThingTwoData",
            () => GetThingTwo(), // ok, GetThingTwo isn't async this time, fudged example
            DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));
    }
}
```

Do you know why MSDTC is being invoked?

Comment: Just for sanity, do you make use of more than one database server or refer to the same server in more than one way, i.e. (localhost -  SERVERNAME - 192.168.2.120) in more than one connection string? Also, could you be referencing two nodes on the same cluster (as you go between nodes on the cluster you have no guarantee which node the connection will end up on).

Comment: Good thought, but it's non-clustered single instance and just one version of the connection string.

Comment: @JasonKleban Did you ever figure this out? I'm finding a transaction is escalated when using async/await and wondered if it is at all related to this.

Comment: I didn't figure out the *why*.  I ended up using `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew` around the data access operation body and a code comment still wondering why the code strictly couldn't work without it.

Answer (score 2):

`PublicationOnly` means that two connections can be created and one thrown away. I'm surprised you made this bug because you explicitly stated `PublicationOnly` (as opposed to the default safety mode which is safe). You explicitly allowed this bug.

For some reason I did not see that you tried `ExecutionAndPublication` already. Since not using it is a bug please fix the code in the question.

`CreateConnection` is also broken in the sense that in case of exception on open the connection object is not getting disposed. Probably harmless but you never know.

Also, audit this code for thread aborts which can happen when ASP.NET times out a request. You are doing very dangerous and brittle things here.

The pattern that I use is to use an IOC container to inject a connection that is shared for the entire request. The first client for that connection opens it. The request end event closes it. Simple, and does away with all that nasty shared, mutable, multi-threaded state.

Why are you using a cache for data that you do not want to lose? This is probably the bug. Don't do that.

What is `?.Value ?? generatorWrapped.Value` about? The dictionary can never return null. Delete that code. If it *could* return null then forcing the lazy value would create a second connection so that's a logic bug as well.

Comment: Regarding `(...)?.Value ?? generatorWrapped.Value`: See that `cache` is not a Dictionary.  ["If the cache does not have a cache entry whose key matches the key parameter, a new cache entry is created, and the MemoryCache.AddOrGetExisting method overload returns null. If a matching cache entry exists, the existing entry is returned."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd988741).  This line takes the existing entry *coalesced to* the newly created lazy entry and evaluates it.  The `Lazy` might be instantiated multiple times but only the successfully cached instatiation will get *evaluated*.

Comment: That Lazy constructor is cheap and cannot not fail.  Then, [`PublicationOnly` means that near-simultaneous initial calls to the cached lazy can execute `GetThingTwo()` more than necessary, but with only one successful result returned as the value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee792409).  I believe that any redundant call is run in the context of the peer-caller preserving that `Transaction.Current` as usual and wouldn't particularly invoke an MSDTC situation.  And multiple evaluations is better here than cached exceptions (until I get rid of inconsistent exceptions like this MSDTC one).

Comment: But thanks for the detailed analysis, a lot of good things for me to think about.  I'll consider your IoC pattern though for improvements and good point about `conn.Open` possibly failing and possible ThreadAbort conditions, though I'm not seeing those causing MSDTC yet either.

Comment: PublicationOnly means that two connection can be opened. Do you agree? That instantly causes MSDTC involvement.

Comment: Also note the point about MemoryCache being allowed to throw away your items (especially at 1min timeout which I just noticed!). That also means that two connections can be created. Do you agree?

Comment: "(...)?.Value ?? generatorWrapped.Value": OK, if that is the behavior of MemoryCache then `?.Value` can indeed be null and you are correct. What crazy API design is this?! Anyway, you can't use MemoryCache because it throws away your data.

Comment: Only if the two attempts are from with the same transaction.  But here each attempt, though near simultaneous, would be within their own independent Transactions (by each encapsulating async-flow preserved TransactionScope) and thus not be cause to escalate either transaction.  If that assumption is incorrect I'm looking to understand it thoroughly!

Comment: OK, if there is no per-key concurrency then this is fine but you don't need the lazy at all.

Comment: The cached data is readonly and changed infrequently.  So it is ok that this kind of data get thrown away - it will get replaced by the more recent data which for this case is acceptable.  Like, options for a dropdown menu that change maybe once a quarter (but I don't know when) but are not read-optimized for whatever reason in the dataset.

Comment: OK, I think I was a bit confused about what you are storing in that cache.

Comment: Lazy *is* required.  AddOrGetExisting takes a value, not a generator.  The value supplied, if not this lazy, would be a new opened connection *every time* possibly to be discarded.

Comment: OK, I'll stop talking trash now. I hope this discussion has helped you in some way. Just ignore the confused parts :)

Comment: I really appreciate the discussion.  Helps rule things out at least!